# In Python, how do I generate random data sets within a range, that follow a function's output?

Tags: python-3.x

For instance, this works to return N data points according to the function timestwo(x), but fails to use the whole mymin to mymax range because random.random() returns floats between 0.0 and 1.0. Any advice?

```
def GenerateDataFromFunction(N,mymin,mymax,myfunc):
    out = []

    while len(out) < N:
        inputvar = myfunc(random.random())
        if inputvar > mymin and inputvar < mymax:
            out.append(inputvar) 
    return out

def timestwo(x):
    return 2*x

GenerateDataFromFunction(10,0,15,timestwo)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want random numbers between `mymin` and `mymax` you can use `random.randrange(mymin, mymax)`. This would only constrain the input though and not the output. It's not going to be possible to always return outputs in the range since that requires insight into how `myfunc` is implemented. For example, your min and max might be 0 and 1 respectively and the function could always return -1 and therefore no matter what arguments you pass it as inputs it will never produce correct outputs. E.g:

```
def myFunc(arg1):
    return -1

GenerateDataFromFunction(10, 0, 1, myFunc)  # This never returns
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to generate a list of discrete values along the function and within the range then use `random.choice()`.